# Commit untracked files to repository

Tags: git, compass-sass, gitignore

When using Compass/Sass I usually put the generated `style.css`and sprites in my `.gitignore` file, so they don't clutter up my commits.

But now I have the case that I `git push` to a online system, but my `style.css` and sprites are not pushed since they are ignored/not committed.

Now I'm wondering if there is a way that I still have those files not committed but they are uploaded to my online repositry when I do `git push`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, I think this is basically asking "Can I have `git` track untracked files?".  What I would do in this situation is create a temporary release push branch and commit the ignored files.  So something like:

```
git checkout -b release-branch
git add -f **/*.css
git commit -m "Temporary release commit"
git push -f deploy release-branch
# Now get rid of the branch since it's deployed.
git checkout master
git branch -D release-branch
```

The downside of this strategy is the `git push -f`.  When doing things this way the deployed website never be an ancestor of what you're pushing and will require a force push.  Whether or not this is a problem or bothers you is largely personal preference.